# I want to delete A column from B column. how can i do it?

Tags: python

I want to delete nm.csv from xc.csv

That means I want to delete the values from Column A which is already in the column B and prints the result.

for eg A - B = result.

I have attached the two nm.csv and xc.csv files below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VTzUR-cfto9EYEnL8gtt5HFIAA-YgzjJoON1XSMwL2M/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14YUmW4KetembqsugwNqshaGjbSidExMVCN4pLeTf5JQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my script I wrote and I dont know what am I doing wrong?

```
import os

with open('/Users/robinmalhotra/Desktop/nm.csv') as nm:
    first = nm.read().splitlines()

with open('/Users/robinmalhotra/Desktop/xc.csv') as xc:
    second = xc.read().splitlines()

bigb = set(first) - set(second)

with open('nm.csv', 'w') as f1:
    out = '\n'.join(list(bigb))
    f1.write(out)
```

I am getting result as nm.csv but I want to delete nm - xc = result.
I am getting A - B = B anyone can tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you mean is, want to remove all the rows in `xc` from `nm`.  Right?

Comment: I mean to delete repeated values. For eg  Column A - Column B = result

Answer (score 1):

This small modification extracts only the first column from the two files:

```
import os

with open('/Users/robinmalhotra/Desktop/nm.csv') as nm:
    first = [ln.strip().split(',')[0] for ln in nm.readlines()]

with open('/Users/robinmalhotra/Desktop/xc.csv') as xc:
    second = [ln..strip().split(',')[0] for ln in xc.readlines()]

bigb = set(first) - set(second)

with open('nm.csv', 'w') as f1:
    out = '\n'.join(list(bigb))
    f1.write(out)
```

Comment: still getting the same result A-B =B

Comment: Did you print `first` and `second` to make sure they have what you expect?  And you originally said you wanted to delete `nm` from `xc`, which would be `set(second) - set(first)`.

Comment: There are some values in column B which I want to delete from column A and print the result. That's it.

Comment: Your question says both "remove nm from xc" and "remove xc from nm".  Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` library should help you read the files cleanly. The source files seem to have a different number of columns, so the `set.difference` method won't work because they aren't alike.